# QueryLocator timeout problem?

Tags: apex, visualforce, exception, querylocator

I have a StandardSetController that I navigate through pages... from a VF page. However, if I let the web page sit for around 15 min or so (not sure about the time) and then try and click the next or previous buttons I get the following error.

> "This page uses a QueryLocator that is invalid. There is a limit of 5
>   QueryLocators per user."

Any idea how to catch this exception or fix the issue?

Code:

```
public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
        get{
            if(setCon == null){
                size = 10;
                string queryString = 'Select Name, Type, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingCountry from Account order by Name';
                setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(queryString));
                setCon.setPageSize(size);
                noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();
            }
            return setCon;
        }set;
    }

    Public List<Account> getAccounts(){
        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        for(Account a : (List<Account>)setCon.getRecords())
            accList.add(a);
        return accList;
    }
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value="|<" action="{!setCon.first}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasPrevious}" title="First Page"/>
<apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value="<" action="{!setCon.previous}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasPrevious}" title="Previous Page"/>
<apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value=">" action="{!setCon.next}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasNext}" title="Next Page"/>
<apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value=">|" action="{!setCon.last}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasNext}" title="Last Page"/>
```

Comment: FYI (unanswered) from 2012 ["This page uses a QueryLocator that is invalid. There is a limit of 5 QueryLocators per user."](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000090bDIAQ). But no mention of time delay there.